# python - selecting rows from an array based on some elements from a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataset

I have a 2d array with values, the first element represents an ID for the data that follows in that row. Ex for a row in my array: [1,45,32,54], 1 is the key and the rest of the numbers are values related to that key. In my array I have different keys numbered from 1-9 but I want to create a second array with filtered values from a list with ID's.

This is the function that I use:

```
def filter_set(dataset, l):
    row=np.where(np.all(dataset[:,0] in l))

    filtered = np.take(dataset,row[0],axis=0)

    return filtered
```

This is how I call it:

```
two_train_set = filter_set(train_set, [0, 1])
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If someone could help me I would be very thankful, thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*I want to create a second array with filtered values from a list with ID's*"? Also add your input dataset and your expected output as well (if the array is large add a smaller version).

Comment: I don't think `in` is numpy aware. You may want to try `np.in1d` and probably get rid of the `np.all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keys only range between 1 and 9 I recommend using a lookup table:

```
>>> def filter_set(dataset, l):
...     mask = np.zeros((10,), dtype=bool)
...     mask[l] = True
...     return dataset[mask[dataset[:, 0]], :]
...
```

Demo:

```
>>> dataset = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 4))
>>> dataset[:, 0] = dataset[:, 0] % 9 + 1
>>> dataset
array([[ 6, 44, 93, 41],
       [ 6, 29, 81, 25],
       [ 6, 63, 65, 71],
       [ 8, 94, 79, 64],
       [ 8, 79, 52, 84],
       [ 8, 60, 94,  2],
       [ 3, 81, 55, 94],
       [ 1, 69, 45,  2],
       [ 8,  1,  9, 98],
       [ 9, 75, 26, 76]])
>>> filter_set(dataset, [5,6,1])
array([[ 6, 44, 93, 41],
       [ 6, 29, 81, 25],
       [ 6, 63, 65, 71],                                                                                            
       [ 1, 69, 45,  2]])
```

Your original approach can also be made to work by replacing `in` with `np.in1d`. Note that I also replaced `np.take` with advanced indexing - which I believe is the more modern way of doing the same thing:

```
>> def filter_set_OP(dataset, l):
...     row = np.in1d(dataset[:, 0], l)
...     return dataset[row, :]
... 
>>> filter_set_OP(dataset, [5,6,1])
array([[ 6, 44, 93, 41],
       [ 6, 29, 81, 25],
       [ 6, 63, 65, 71],
       [ 1, 69, 45,  2]])
```